# Flask application doesn't have access to updated db information / Flask sqlalchemy not removing session

Tags: mysql, nginx, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, gunicorn

I am working on my first web app (Flask) and have progressed to the point where I am deploying it.  For the db and orm, the app uses mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy. For deployment, I am using gunicorn and nginx.

Its all set up and I am able to access the site on the external server.  The issue I am having is that when data is entered and I then search for it, the application is not able to consistently access it (i.e. when new user registers, they can't login even though their information is in mysql db).  By consistently, I mean that I can see the entered data 1 out of every ~5 times I refresh the search. To be clear, the information is making it to the db and the server is returning the flash message saying the data was successfully submitted.

Additionally, I was testing submitting a form when cookies had been deleted.  As expected, it gave me a CSRF error.  However, afterwards, the application wouldn't refresh the cookies.

Both issues resolved themselves once gunicorn was stopped and restarted.

I suspect its an application configuration issue, but haven't figured out what is causing it. The issues do not appear when I am running the app from the flask development server.

**Edit**: To verify it wasn't an external server issue, I ran the gunicorn locally. Once again, I ran into the same issue.  The issue disappeared however, when I reduced the number of workers from 4 to 1.  The inconsistency reappeared when I increased the number of workers from 1 to 2. Whether the app was able to correctly access the db depending on which worker was being used.

Looking at flask-sqlalchemy, when run with the development server I saw that its correctly removing the db session at the end of each request.  However, it is not doing that when I am running with gunicorn?  Does anyone have any thoughts as to what could be causing this?

Below is code for config file

```
**Flask config.py**    
class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")

    #sql alchemy info
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI =  os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False


class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    REMEMBER_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
    SESSION_PROTECTION = "strong"
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    REMEMBER_COOKIE_SECURE = True

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = False


**Supervisor gunicorn configuration**
[program:Ask]
command=/home/ubuntu/Ask/venv/bin/gunicorn -b localhost:8000 -w 4 Ask:app
directory=/home/ubuntu/Ask
user=ubuntu
autostart=true
autorestar=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
```

Thanks in advance.  Please let me know if there's any additional information that would be helpful.